# CakePHP how to submit NULL value?

Tags: cakephp, null

On web form I have select-option field. It have to submit value 'card' (without quotes), or NULL value.

Now, code looks like this:

```
    $options = array(NULL => 'Invoice', 'card' => 'Payment card');
    echo $this->Form->input('payment_method', array('options'=>$options));
```

How can I define options array, to submit NULL value in database table (and/or 'card', but that works of course), in case that Invoice option is selected?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You cannot "POST" NULL values in PHP. Only empty strings. But you can map them to NULL values in the controller or preferably the model layer prior to saving. With "default NULL" as field setting this should automatically be done by Cake AFAIK.

Comment: There are some CakePHP plugins around that convert empty strings to NULL when inserting into a database.  Might be helpful for some: https://github.com/robwilkerson/CakePHP-NullableBehavior‎

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NULL is an invalid key for an associative array. Only 'integers' and 'strings' are valid array keys, see the documentation: [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

To send an empty value through the form, you can use an empty string. To force inserting a NULL value in the database, handle this inside your model or controller before saving

```
$options = array('' => 'Invoice', 'card' => 'Payment card');
echo $this->Form->input('payment_method', array('options'=>$options));
```

Then inside your controller;

```
if ('' === $this->request->data['MyModelName']['payment_method']) {
     this->request->data['MyModelName']['payment_method'] = null;
}
```

### Alternative approach

However, why not use a *value* for the 'invoice' payment method? Like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('payment_method', array(
    'options' => array(
        ''        => 'Select your payment method..',
        'invoice' => 'Invoice',
        'card'    => 'Payment card',
    )
));
```

IMO this has some advantages;

- it's more transparent, e.g. When looking inside the database, it's clear that the payment method is 'invoice'. By using a 'special' value (null), people without knowledge of your applications inner workings will have to browse through the source code to find out
- it's possible to check if the use has selected a payment method; e.g. If the value is empty, the use may have forgotten to select a payment method, in which case you can mark the field 'invalid' via a validation rule.

Comment: tnx! about your Alternative approach - application is already developed, this is only upgrade, i don't want to change available values, it can cause problems in other part of application.

Comment: Understandable in that case, but still worth considering. Just wanted to make the suggestion to (possibly) improve your code. Anyway, glad I could help and good luck on your project!